# "unable to connect to database"

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to connection to my MySQL database and am getting an "unable to connect to database" exception. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

```
 public class SQL {


        //database variables
        private Connection connection;

        public SQL() {
            // DATABASE CONNECTION
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to find and load driver");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            try {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tools");
            } catch (SQLException e){
                System.out.println("Unable to connect to database");
                System.exit(1);
            }

        }

        public void database() {
            Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
            try {
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = statement
                        .executeQuery("SELECT nameofsong FROM lyrics_lyrics");

                while (rs.next()) {
                    v.addElement(rs.getString("nameofsong"));
                }
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) { }
        }


        private void displaySQLErrors(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState:     " + e.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError:  " + e.getErrorCode());
        }

    }
```

Comment: can you print the stack trace of the exception, using e.printStackTrace(); and post the output.

Comment: Post your full stacktrace please.

Comment: Have you specified a username and password?

Comment: @Andy Pryor i did and it says Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'tools'

Comment: @Jad J as notes in a few answers, try setting the username and password.

Answer (score 3):

In first sight I see that you don't provide a `username` and `password`.

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tools",username,password);
                                                                                ^       ^
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set username and password.

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tools",
                                          "username","password");
```

Comment: ahh, i know my mysql password but is there any way to know the username, i'd forgotten it..

Comment: @JadJ - You can reset the root password - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check your classpath jars ? Does it have jar of mysql ?? It happens if the jar for mysql is not found in classpath because of it, it may not find com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class so throws an exception. Obvously after that you need to take the object of connection as specified by AVD and other people.

Comment: right, the jay is in the classpath and it's all good, everyone's right i just need to specify my username and password, problem is i don't know the username...any way to look up?

Answer (score 0):

I notice you have a private method, "displaySqlErrors(...)".  If you call that method from your catch block, like "displaySqlErrors(e)", then you will likely be able to determine the problem on your own.

Comment: I Used 'root' as the username and passed my password in and it worked! Thank you everybody